# how to get application name from the intent received in the broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android

My application listens for the `outgoing_call_broadcast`. I need to know in my broadcast receiver whether the call is made from the dialer app or from the saved contacts?

Comment: what is the code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

why dont u match the intents for dialer and contacts in another receiver and whenever outgoing call broadcast read the data set from the receiver which app is aclled for outgoing call.
Intent.ACTION_DIAL for dialer and Intent.ACTION_PICK for contacts

Comment: Thank you so much user1969053. I think this is gonna solve my problem. But a separate receiver does not make sense to me, because i already have receiver for outgoing calls. 2nd thing, how would i read the data set from the receiver? I am new to Android!

Comment: I got your point but still not getting it right. Please help me how to setup a separate receiver for the ACTION_DIAL and ACTION_PICK. I tried it the why i did for the ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL, but i am not receiving any broadcast for the ACTION_DIAL or ACTION_PICK.

Comment: For data saving you can refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html